# Locations I am willing to work at, Custom Sort

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It would be nice to have the ability to specify the order of the locations where I am willing to work at. Currently the sort order appears to be size or how precise the location is. Locations that contain a city will show before states and countries. Having the same ability to specify order like we do for the experience section would be nice.

Thanks!